# Beamer: Use Libertine and Computer Modern monospace (pdflatex vs lualatex)

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex, libertine

I am using `beamer` to write a presentation.
I included the `libertine` package to change the default font, and I am using the `professionalfonts` theme to avoid clashes with beamer's font settings.

I however dislike Libertine's monospaced family so I would like to revert to Computer Modern for `\tt` text.
Therefore I included `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}` in my preamble.

The problem is that using `pdflatex` I get the desired effect while this breaks using `lualatex`. Can anybody tell me what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Huge\sc
Thanks!

{\Large\tt http://www.nice.website}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With `lualatex`:

[image: lualatex]

With `pdflatex`:

[image: pdflatex]

Comment: I found a workaround by adding the `tt=false` option of `libertine` I can make it work with `lualatex` but I still not understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Seb, the `fontspec` package is often used for handling (OpenType) fonts in LuaLaTeX. However, loading the package is not mandatory (but there are benefits to using OpenType fonts).

According to the [libertine manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf), there is a package option `type1` (or `nofontspec`) for reverting to Type 1 fonts, as used by `pdflatex`. The option is relevant when compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. It will do nothing with `pdflatex`.

The modified document (the same fonts for `lualatex` and `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Huge\sc
Thanks!

{\Large\tt http://www.nice.website}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Without the `type1` option, `libertine` will automatically load `fontspec` when Lua(La)TeX or Xe(La)TeX is used. As a result, the font encoding will be EU2 or EU1, respectively. When the MWE is compiled with `lualatex` (`xelatex`), there is a warning that the font `cmtt` is not available in the EU2 (EU1) encoding, and a substitute font is used instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is because LuaLaTeX handles fonts in a different way.
The equivalents to your working PDFLaTeX options are

```
\usepackage{fontspec} % Font handling
\setmainfont[]{Linux Libertine O} % Main font is Linux Libertine
\setmonofont[]{CMU Typewriter Text} % Monospace font is Computer Modern Typewriter
```

For deeper understanding of what is going on with fonts in LuaLaTeX you may have a look at the [Fontspec package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution that can work for both engines? I mean, this would make it work for `lualatex` only while I was hoping to get something that compiles unchanged with both engines (avoiding `\ifluatex` nonsense)

Comment: Specifically: is `\ttdefault` just ignored by `luatex`?

Comment: Your "workaround" (tt=false option) is the way to get it working for both traditional and emerging engines.